# importing data from many workbooks in different folders

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I am looking to **import/copy** data from many workbooks into a summary workbook.  The workbooks are arranged in different sub-folders, I.e

```
C:\data1\results_2001.xlm
C:\data2\results_2002.xlm
C:\data3\results_2003.xlm
```

The names are similar but differ slightly to differentiate them.  At present, I import the files individually, and I want to automate the process.  The results files (above) are amongst other excel files so I cannot target them by file type.

How would I import these files by partial file name?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create an array of the filepaths to your excel sheets and then loop over the array and get the data you want into your summary sheet.

```
Sub CreateSummary()
    Dim wkbs() As Variant, wkb As Integer, owb As Workbook

    wkbs = Array("C:\data1\results_2001.xlm", "C:\data2\results_2002.xlm", "C:\data3\results_2003.xlm")

    For wkb = 0 To UBound(wkbs)             
         Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open(wkbs(wkb)) //Open each workbook

         With owb
             //Get the data you want into your summary workbook
            .Close
         End With
    Next wkb
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in any languages, but for you who is asking this question, i think it's gonna be a little challenging, so here is what you need to do :

- create a function that will list files/folders from given path
- loop through all items found, if it's a folder , recursive it
- if the item fits your target(name, extension, ...)  , read it and load the content to the summary

something like this, i believe you will achieve this easily using VBA, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

Literally, it will be like this, please note that this is not valid code, just something i write down to help you figure it out :

```
function loopthepath (string pathtoloop)

foreach(dirItem item in pathtoloop.getdirItem)
{
    if (item is folder)
    {
        loopthepath(pathtoloop + item) 
    }
    else 
    {
        if (item fits mydescription)
        {
            load the content to the summary 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I posted a link to a topic which can help you on this task, please read it

Comment: When you mean list the files/folders... Do you mean to input them somewhere in the workbook and reference them from there?

Comment: yes, you can store the folder path in a textbox, a cell, or directly in your code if your path don't change often. i edited and added more detail in my original answer

Comment: Apologies if I sound naive - I am a novice in VBA.  I gave some sample text for someone to help in the coding.

Comment: glad to help, but keep in mind that the real hard part is copying and paste the data to your summary workbook, not the listing folders and files stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way, especially if only a one time operation:  Go into Cmd.exe, do a Dir for the files you're looking for, and send it to a text file (eg, something like `dir c:\results_*.xlm /s /b > c:\myList.txt`).  Then import the text file to your worksheet, step thru each cell in the list, opening each workbook in turn.

Comment: Perhaps I should have elaborated more earlier... I am trying to take this one step at a time.  The workbooks/sheets have formulas which I need in the results summary.  Once I import, I will also need to change the source link to the results summary so that the formulas are functional within the summary workbook.  I presume I will need to do this after each workbook is copied.